# Parsing command line arguments of different formats

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to convert command line arguments to different formats. For example, if I'm trying to get a specific user, it would be `GetUser=UserName`, but I also have methods that don't need the equals sign, such as `GetAllUsers`. Right now I'm currently splitting on the `=` but I don't need to do that for all commands. I tried setting it to a conditional, where if `=` is detected, it will split, otherwise it will just take the argument as a string, but I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`

Code:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseArgs(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string arg in args)
            {
                string[] parts = arg.Split('=');
                if (parts.Length > 1)
                {
                    results[parts[0]] = parts[1];
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    results = Convert.ToString(arg);
                }

            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: `results = Convert.ToString(arg);` think about what this line is doing, what the type of `results` is, and why it's a problem.

Comment: Look into the `CommandLineParser` library. Git here - https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline. It makes parsing command line args much simpler. The problem you are currently facing is trying to assign a string to a dictionary type. That obviously will not work. You could probably do `results.Add(arg, arg)` to have the key be the same as the value, but thats pretty spaghetti to me. You'd be much better off using the correct tool for the job.

Comment: You might replace the `if/else` with `results[parts[0]] = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : "";`

Comment: That worked perfectly @RufusL, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a string to a dictionary object. If you want a collection (like Dictionary) then you should use the Add method like so:

```
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        string[] parts = arg.Split('=');
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            //results[parts[0]] = parts[1];
            results.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add("GetUser", arg);
        }

    }
```

I've forced it to be "GetUser" as the value here, but you may actually want something different. Your dictionary is using Key-Value pairs and you would say results["GetUser"] to return a string for "GetUser". You could also use [TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) to validate that GetUser was actually provided.

Additionally, if you just want to return the string that's after GetUser (e.g. Username), then you could change results to a string and just assign that directly and skip the whole use of a Dictionary, which seems overkill for your sample (perhaps your real project is much more complex though).

Comment: Also, if you want to add it your original way, you would just want to change the else statement to us results["GetUser"] = arg;

Answer (score 0):

In the else part, you are trying to assign string to dictionary via the statement                     `results = Convert.ToString(arg);`

So, please change else part with something like as shown below:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ParseArgs(string[] args)
{
     Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     foreach (string arg in args)
     {
          string[] parts = arg.Split('=');
          if (parts.Length > 1)
          {
               results[parts[0]] = parts[1];
               // continue; no need to use continue, as there are no more statements after this if-else, loop will anyway continue. but please uncomment if you have any in your actual code.
          }
          else
          {
               results[arg] = arg; // assuming arg string in args won't repeat, meaning its unique. Otherwise please use ContaineKey if condition before adding or over-writing.
           }
     }
     return results;
}
```

Comment: "arg" is already a string. See the above segment "foreach (**string arg** in args)". Additionally, assigning the value to both value and key in Dictionary might necessitate looping through a Dictionary, which while it can be done would somewhat defeat the entire point of using a Dictionary type in the first place. (Not that OP's sample is a good use case either.)

Comment: @JoshMaag thank you for pointing on ToString conversion out. I agree and I will update the post. Its merely copy+paste error on my side. For the second part, since I don't know what to use for key, I just used the same string which OP can replace with whatever it makes sense to him/her. I just tried to remove the error that he is getting.